# Setting vertical height components with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Cannot find out how to set all components centered vertically depending on the "select"  height (and remove this dirty "padding" trick !!)

```
  <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group" >
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="padding-top:25px;">test</label>
      <div class="col-sm-2 " style="padding-top:20px;">
        <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">

        <select multiple class="form-control">
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a Try

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group" >
        <div class="clearfix align-items">
        <div>
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2">test</label>
        </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2 ">
        <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select multiple class="form-control">
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
            <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
            <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
</div>

    </div>
  </form>
```

CSS

```
.align-items
   {
    display: table;
   }
   .align-items > div
   {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      float: none;
   }
```

or try using flex-box

hope this helps..